# 'aws iam list-users' command throwing an error in AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I was trying `aws iam list-users` command in AWS CLI which is failing with error:

> "could not be found saml". Please help to resolve.

Error shown as below:

```
➜ ~ aws iam list-users

) could not be foundsaml

➜ ~
```

I have set up AWS CLI in Mac properly. Tried to login in aws.

But it did not resolve. Please help.

Comment: Do any other commands work for you (for example `aws s3 ls`)? Are you authenticating via an SSO provider?